# Try different versions of website addresses - Python

Tags: python, web, verify

I am using variables from the list "names" to request value points from a website:

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Actually I have a lot more values in names than this.

The plan was to iterate over the following adress and fill in my variables like this:

```
def get_values(name):
    res = requests.get('www.example.com/tb/' + name)

for name in names:
    get_values(name)
```

The problem is, a part of the adress changes for the different values to three different values (tb, az and dm)(they are always the same for the different names):

- www.example.com/tb/A
- www.example.com/tb/B
- www.example.com/az/C
- www.example.com/dm/D
- www.example.com/dm/E

For this reason in my code above only the values for A and B get downloaded. (And it is not practible to assign the variables to the names or vice versa.)

So my plan to get the correct URL was to solve this problem with if/else:

```
try:
    r = requests.get('www.example.com/tb/' + stock)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        url = 'www.example.com/tb/' + stock
    else:
        r = requests.get('www.example.com/az/' + stock)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            url = 'www.example.com/az/' + stock
        else:
            url = 'www.example.com/dm/' + stock
except:
    pass

correctUrl = requests.get(url)
```

This only gives me the values for one variable (e.g. tz). 
I also have tried to find a solution with try and except and also with some variations of try/except and if/else but it's not working.

It would be nice if someone can give me advice how I can verify the correct address for each name in my list. Or what is the most pythonic way to do this. Unfortunately I was not able to find an approach on stackoverflow or google.

Comment: `(they are always the same for the different names)` so why not store them in the list in the first place ?

Comment: why can't you have `['tb/A', 'tb/B', 'az/C', 'dm/D', 'dm/E']` and iterate over that, however you get to having a list like that is another question based on number of variations and such

Comment: @MooingRawr: They are always the same, but I only have the names in my "names" list. I don't know which name has which variable.

Comment: @aws_apprentice: see my answer for MooingRawr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the possible url's until you get a code `200`:

```
def get_url(name):
    for sub in ('tb', 'az', 'dm'):
        url = f'www.example.com/{sub}/{name}'
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return url
    return None    

for name in names:
    url = get_url(name)
    print(url)
```

> Obviously, it would be much better if you could store those paths within your names, something like [(tb, A), (tb, B), (az, C), ...]. But i assume you can't?

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now. You are assuming right. Unfortunately it isn't practical to figure out which name belongs to which variable/sub.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If the answer helped you solve your problem, could you mark it as solved?